# Unable to Upload File Via POST From Qt to PHP Script

Tags: php, c++, qt, post

I'm trying to upload a file via POST from a Qt (C++) application to my webserver, running a LAMP stack.

All seems to go well, but for some reason, the script's `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays are completely empty. I've tried uploading the same file with a plain HTML form, and it works.

Here's how I construct the request inside my Qt program:

```
request.setUrl(ServerAddress);
request.setHeader(request.ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
reply = nam.post(request, file);
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Where `request` is a `QNetworkRequest`, `reply` is a `QNetworkReply`, `nam` is a QNetworkAccessManager, and `file` is the open `QFile` for my file.

The request sends fine, and I've even tried to see if somehow the request got messed up by using Wireshark. Here's the output:

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 8
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: mysite.com

My data!HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 15:16:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.17RC1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 36
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

It's a very small text file, and only contains "'My data!". I just don't get why the PHP script isn't seeing the file. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: i have always used `multipart/form-data` for file uploads

Comment: Hmmm when I use that type, my arrays are still empty, but I get a php warning: `Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown in line 0`

Comment: you have to construct your post with boundaries.

Comment: I think @DevZer0 is right, you should use multipart/form-data

Comment: I'll try adding the boundaries, and I'll post back

Comment: That worked, thanks DevZer0. If you post an answer, I'll accept it